# Binding a single element twice doesn't work in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, bind

If I run following program twice the `click` event  is never fired. However if I do it three times it works. Why is this?

```
function categorychange() {
    $('.card').click(function() {
        $(this).children().children("p").children().toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('mdl');
        $('.mdl-black').toggle();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because each time you add an event handler to the `.card` element you're adding another call to `toggle()` the specified elements. When you toggle something an even number of times it goes back to the state it was originally in, hence nothing appears to be happening.

To fix this, it sounds like a delegated event handler would better suit your needs. This way you can assign the event handler when the page loads, and don't have to re-bind the same event multiple times. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.card', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('mdl').children().children("p").children().toggle();
    $('.mdl-black').toggle();
});
```

Alternatively you could use `off()` to unbind the existing event handlers before binding new ones in the `categorychange()` function:

```
function categorychange(){
    $('.card').off().click(function() { // note .off() here
        $(this).toggleClass('mdl').children().children("p").children().toggle();
        $('.mdl-black').toggle();
    });
}
```

Note that the former example, using a delegated event handler, is by *far* the better solution here.